# Validate phone number with Symfony

Tags: regex, symfony

I want to validate the phone nummer in a form. I would like to check so number and the "(" and ")" char are valid only. So user can fill in +31(0)600000000. The +31 is already preset in the form. The number only is possible with the code below, only how to add the two chars?

Or is there a standaard better way to validate phone number?

```
 @Assert\Length(min = 8, max = 20, minMessage = "min_lenght", maxMessage = "max_lenght")
 @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[0-9]*$/", message="number_only")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex you need is:

```
/^\(0\)[0-9]*$
```

or for the entire number

```
/^\+31\(0\)[0-9]*$
```

You can test and play around with your regex here (it also includes auto-generated explanations):
https://www.regex101.com/r/gD0hE5/1

Comment: Is it also possible that (0) is not required but optional? So both (0)600000000 and 600000000 is valid.

Comment: `/^(\(0\))?[0-9]+$/` would allow the optional `(0)`. You could also make the `+31` & the `(0)` optional but both required when using the `+31` by using `^((\+31)?\(0\))?[0-9]+$`. So `+31(0)60..`, `(0)60..` & `60..` would be valid while `+3160..` would not.

Comment: You could also add `{9}` after the `[0-9]` to only allow a string of 9 numbers like `/^(\(0\))?[0-9]{9}$/` meaning `(0)600000000` would be valid while `(0)600000` would not.

Answer (score 11):

If you need a good and robust validator for numbers, with advanced options to valudate, I will advice to use google lib https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber, there is existed symfony2 bundle https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle and you can see there is a assert annotation:

```
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Validator\Constraints\PhoneNumber as AssertPhoneNumber;

/**
 * @AssertPhoneNumber
 */
private $phoneNumber;
```

Comment: Is it possible to manage compound fields with this bundle? I.e. having country prefix and number splitted across two form fields?

Comment: not sure how exactly you want to "manage", but you can merge the fields to $string and use a service as "$phoneNumber = $container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->parse($string, PhoneNumberUtil::UNKNOWN_REGION);"

Comment: By manage I mean doing the merging automatically like Doctrine does for Money Value Object for example

Comment: I believe that bundle has not such functionality, but there is a space to extend and create for own needs